# Assets: Updating Indexes Freezes

Tags: assets

When I try to update the index for an upload directory, the progress bar will freeze at a certain point. The first time I run the update, it freezes fairly early, but sometimes if I refresh the page and run the update again, the bar will progress quickly, then freeze in the middle or about 3/4 of the way.

Assets works perfectly on my local WAMP server. It's only on the production server where this issue is occurring.

I get this console error multiple times when running the update index:

```
POST https://www.mysite.com/ 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:177
Uncaught Internal Server Error, admin.php:389
```

All of my upload directories are 777 permissions.

The URL I'm using to access the control panel matches the Site URL in General Configuration.

The `system/expressionengine/cache` directory has 777 permissions.

I'm using *absolute* paths for my File Upload Preferences on my local environment.

External sources are *not* included.

I also cleared out my .htaccess file except for these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ----------------------------------
# Keep WWW Rule the topmost rule.
# ----------------------------------

# Redirect non-www URLs to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force SSL 
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L] 

# Remove index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This problem coincides with other Assets uploading issues, but I figured I'd start with this.

- EE 2.6.1
- Assets 2.1.3

Comment: Did you check your /system/expressionengine/cache folder for 777 permissions?  And are you using relative or absolute paths for your local file upload preferences? And are external sources included?  I'd also love to know the version of EE and Assets.  Lastly - do you see any errors in your browser's debug console?  If you can add that info to your original post I can help out a lot more.  Thank you!

Comment: @LisaWess I've updated the question with the information you asked for - sorry for forgetting the version numbers! I imagine that console error has something to do with it...

Comment: Do you have access to the server error logs?  It looks like we need to see those! Also, what other Assets uploading issues? I wonder if they're connected. :)

Comment: It's shared hosting, so I don't have personal access to the error logs. But I contacted support and they said there weren't any errors in the log.

Comment: What's on line 389 of your admin.php, Kirsten? Does it look like a normal admin.php from a fresh download?  Have you tried re-uploading that file?  It may be time for us to login and have a look - can Super Admin and FTP details be sent to support@pixelandtonic.com? Please do reference this thread!

Comment: This'll blow your mind: there is no line 389 on admin.php, it stops at 202. I'll shoot you an email, thanks.

Comment: @Lisa Andris ended up solving this for me via email (tickets 12981 & 13228). Something to do with the Securit:ee add-on, but I forgot what the solution was specifically. Would you please post the solution/explanation for others? Thanks.